# Getting the date by week using dimension ga:week

Tags: google-analytics

Im confused how to get the date in my weekly report chart. How can I get the range since its filtered by week, I want my dates to be per week like: Aug 01, 2019 to Aug 04, 2019 and so on...

Here's Im trying to get:

```
data = [

 {
   date: "Aug 01, 2019 to Aug 03, 2019",
   data: {
     bounces: "123",
     views: "123",
     sessions: "123,
   }
 },
 {
   date: "Aug 04, 2019 to Aug 10, 2019",
   data: {
     bounces: "123",
     views: "123",
     sessions: "123,
   }
 },
 up to end date ...

]
```

Any suggestion, advice? no to hate please Im just new to google analytics.